# Comparing coefficients in logistic regression with curvilinear effects

Tags: logistic, regression-coefficients

I’m conducting a multiple logistic regression with 3 predictors (*x*, *y* and *z*). A Box-Tidwell test suggested that the relation between x and the dependent variable is not linear on the logit, so I have added the squared term (*x*^2) to the equation. All the coefficients are statistically significant, but my question is: how can I compare the relative impact of each predictor, now that *x* does not have a single coefficient (or odds ratio), but two?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I came across this paper that basically answers my question:

Mize, T. D. (2019). Best practices for estimating, interpreting, and presenting nonlinear interaction effects. Sociological Science, 6, 81-117.
(https://sociologicalscience.com/articles-v6-4-81/)

In sum: do not report regression coefficients when curvilinear effects or interaction terms are included in the model. Instead, determine the size and significance of the effects using marginal effects.